# Error while starting Cassandra for first time

Tags: cassandra

I am attempting to start Cassandra for the first time on a Redhat machine. I have successfully done so on my practice Ubuntu machines, but for some reason, the Redhat install is giving me the following errors:

> INFO  [main] 2017-06-29 20:11:42,369 YamlConfigurationLoader.java:89 - Configuration location: file:/home/cassandra/apache-cassandra-3.10/conf/cassandra.yaml
>   Exception (org.apache.cassandra.exceptions.ConfigurationException) encountered during startup: Invalid yaml: file:/home/cassandra/apache-cassandra-3.10/conf/cassandra.yaml
>    Error: null; Can't construct a java object for tag:yaml.org,2002:org.apache.cassandra.config.Config; exception=Cannot create property=data_file_directories for JavaBean=org.apache.cassandra.config.Config@12405818; No single argument constructor found for class [Ljava.lang.String;;  in 'reader', line 10, column 1:
>       cluster_name: 'Test Cluster'
>
> ^
>
> Invalid yaml:
>   file:/home/cassandra/apache-cassandra-3.10/conf/cassandra.yaml  Error:
>   null; Can't construct a java object for
>   tag:yaml.org,2002:org.apache.cassandra.config.Config; exception=Cannot
>   create property=data_file_directories for
>   JavaBean=org.apache.cassandra.config.Config@12405818; No single
>   argument constructor found for class [Ljava.lang.String;;  in
>   'reader', line 10, column 1:
>       cluster_name: 'Test Cluster'
>   ^
>
> ERROR [main] 2017-06-29 20:11:42,742 CassandraDaemon.java:752 -
>   Exception encountered during startup: Invalid yaml:
>   file:/home/cassandra/apache-cassandra-3.10/conf/cassandra.yaml  Error:
>   null; Can't construct a java object for
>   tag:yaml.org,2002:org.apache.cassandra.config.Config; exception=Cannot
>   create property=data_file_directories for
>   JavaBean=org.apache.cassandra.config.Config@12405818; No single
>   argument constructor found for class [Ljava.lang.String;;  in
>   'reader', line 10, column 1:
>       cluster_name: 'Test Cluster'

The only change I made to yaml is I set the data and log files as follows:

> data_file_directories: /var/lib/cassandra/data
>
> commitlog_directory: /var/log/cassandra/commitlog

This is a single node to get it working proof of concept machine. Can I solicite some assistance from you much more experienced users?

Thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The problem was with the yaml file :

> data_file_directories: /var/lib/cassandra/data

It needed to be:

> data_file_directories:
>       - /var/lib/cassandra/data